# I am trying to pass an anchor tag's ID to jquery but it is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I am using fancy box and I am trying to open a link with its pop up image.

My html that opens the fancybox image

```
<div id="isotope">
        <a href="img/portfolio/digitallifeWebsite.png" class="item branding webdesign" data-fancy="gal" id="http://www.digitallife.space/"><img src="img/portfolio/digitallifeWebsite.png" alt="digital life website"></a>
        <a href="img/portfolio/redandwhite.png" class="item branding webdesign" data-fancy="gal" id="http://www.redandwhiteinsight.com/"><img src="img/portfolio/redandwhite.png" alt="Red and white insight"></a>
</div>
```

The jquery that activates fancybox when you click the image

```
lightBox: function() {
  $('#isotope a').fancybox({
    onComplete: function () {
        $("#fancybox-img").wrap($("<a />", {
            // set anchor attributes
            href: this.id, // THIS DOESN'T WORK
            target: "_blank" 
        }));
    }
});
},
```

This is apart of some code I got now I am modifying it for myself. Not sure wehat "lightBox" is.

When I change the href to

```
href: this.href,
```

Or

```
href: 'http://www.google.com/'
```

It works

but

```
href: this.id,
```

Does not work! How can I make it use the id for the href stuff?

My console.log for ($this)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcCC5.jpg

Comment: Can you check the value of $(this) by using console.log() and let me know.

Comment: @Aparna I don't see the ID attribute when I console.log this.

Comment: What you are getting, show me.

Comment: @Aparna I added an image of it to my post

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$(this).attr('id');`?

Anyway, I think is better change the attribute **id** in **data-id** and using `$(this).attr('data-id');`.

Comment: Yup tried both. Both times the anchor tag becomes <a target="_blank"> whereas with this.href or a url it actually sets the href

Answer (score 0):

there is multiple anchor tag so may be you need to wrap each anchor tag

Comment: How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving your value in id attribute, give it in the rel attribute of anchor tag and then check $(this).attr('rel');

Answer (score 0):

The issue takes place because `this` have another context, not anchor.

Where is the handler for the `click` (on image) event? You gave very little information about your task.

Anyway, to implement what you want, you can do like this (it's just a simple example, I don't know what does your code look like):

```
$('img').on('click', function() {
  // "this" equal to the element on which you clicked
  var href = $(this).closest('a') // find anchor
                    .attr('id'); // get attribute id
});
```

And pass "href" (you can make him global variable if needed)

```
// ...
onComplete: function () {
  $("#fancybox-img").wrap($("<a />", {
    href: href,
    target: "_blank"
  }));
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed this with this code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#isotope a').each(function(i) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).fancybox({
            onComplete: function () {

                $("#fancybox-img").wrap($("<a />", {
                    // set anchor attributes
                    href: id, //or your target link
                    target: "_blank"
                }));
            }
        });
        });

});
```